# Calculate fold change based on 3 columns of variables in R

Tags: r

I have a df

```
A    B    C     D
C1   NI   0     4
C1   NI   15    8
C1   NI   29    16
C2   NP   0     1
C2   NP   28    2
C2   NP   35    1
C2   NP   49    4
```

```
A <- c("C1","C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C2")
B <- c("NI","NI", "NI", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP")
C <- c("0","15", "29", "0", "28", "35", "49")
D <- c("4", "8", "16", "1", "2", "1", "4")
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

I would like to calculate the l̶o̶g̶2̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶d̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ fold change of values from Column D based on the variables from all of the other three columns

My current code so far is not giving me my desired output:

```
library(gtools)

df2 <- df %>% group_by(A,B,C) %>% 
mutate(E = logratio2foldchange(D))
```

I am getting values of #.###+06 for E row 1 and E row 4, aka non zero values.

My desired df2 is:

```
   A    B    C     D    E
1  C1   NI   0     4    0
2  C1   NI   15    8    2
3  C1   NI   29    16   4
4  C2   NP   0     1    0
5  C2   NP   28    2    2
6  C2   NP   35    1    0
7  C2   NP   49    4    4
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Good eye akrun.  I think I misinterpreted what I actually need to calculate which is just fold change, NOT log2 fold change.  I will now edit my question to reflect this, but of course my gtools code of "logratio2foldchange" is innacurate and the other gtools requires an input of foldchange(num, denom), which I currently do not have my df set up as.

Comment: The fold change of the baseline, aka column D rows 1 and 4 should be zero. I have taken a look at other codes for such a problem, but I think that requires me rearranging the df with multiple columns to represent the values from Column D?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
There are 2 possible errors:

1. `C` and `D` are `character` use `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`
2. The other thing is that your example dataframe has got different numbers in column `C`.

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
    mutate(E = logratio2foldchange(D))
```

```
  A     B         C     D     E
  <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 C1    NI        0     4    16
2 C1    NI       15     8   256
3 C1    NI       29    16 65536
4 C2    NP        0     1     2
5 C2    NP       28     2     4
6 C2    NP       35     1     2
7 C2    NP       49     4    16
```